# Why doesn't tmux source work? Unknown command

Tags: debian, tmux

How can I fix this issue?
This is the code and output I received. This is tmux 2.3 and debian 8.9.

```
root@ns540540:/# tmux source ~/.tmux.conf
/root/.tmux.conf:1: unknown command: @plugin
/root/.tmux.conf:2: unknown command: assume-paste-time
/root/.tmux.conf:3: unknown command: base-index
/root/.tmux.conf:4: unknown command: bell-action
/root/.tmux.conf:5: unknown command: bell-on-alert
/root/.tmux.conf:6: unknown command: default-command
/root/.tmux.conf:7: unknown command: default-shell
/root/.tmux.conf:8: unknown command: destroy-unattached
/root/.tmux.conf:9: unknown command: detach-on-destroy
/root/.tmux.conf:10: unknown command: display-panes-active-colour
/root/.tmux.conf:11: unknown command: display-panes-colour
/root/.tmux.conf:12: unknown command: display-panes-time
/root/.tmux.conf:13: unknown command: display-time
/root/.tmux.conf:14: unknown command: history-limit
/root/.tmux.conf:15: unknown command: key-table
/root/.tmux.conf:16: unknown command: lock-after-time
/root/.tmux.conf:17: unknown command: lock-command
/root/.tmux.conf:18: unknown command: message-command-style
/root/.tmux.conf:19: unknown command: message-style
/root/.tmux.conf:20: unknown command: mouse
/root/.tmux.conf:21: unknown command: prefix
/root/.tmux.conf:22: unknown command: prefix2
/root/.tmux.conf:23: unknown command: renumber-windows
/root/.tmux.conf:24: unknown command: repeat-time
/root/.tmux.conf:25: unknown command: set-remain-on-exit
/root/.tmux.conf:26: unknown command: set-titles
/root/.tmux.conf:27: unknown command: set-titles-string
/root/.tmux.conf:28: unknown command: status
/root/.tmux.conf:29: unknown command: status-interval
/root/.tmux.conf:30: unknown command: status-justify
/root/.tmux.conf:31: unknown command: status-keys
/root/.tmux.conf:32: unknown command: status-left
/root/.tmux.conf:33: unknown command: status-left-length
/root/.tmux.conf:34: unknown command: status-left-style
/root/.tmux.conf:35: unknown command: status-position
/root/.tmux.conf:36: unknown command: status-right
/root/.tmux.conf:37: unknown command: status-right-length
/root/.tmux.conf:38: unknown command: status-right-style
/root/.tmux.conf:39: unknown command: status-style
/root/.tmux.conf:40: unknown command: update-environment
/root/.tmux.conf:41: unknown command: visual-activity
/root/.tmux.conf:42: unknown command: visual-bell
/root/.tmux.conf:43: unknown command: visual-silence
/root/.tmux.conf:44: unknown command: word-separators
```

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Are you sure you want to run `.tmux.conf` from root?

Answer (score 2):

Per the [`tmux` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html), `~/.tmux.conf` is the default location for a personal `tmux` configuration file, so it will be read and applied automatically when you invoke `tmux` without needing to specify it in any way.  If you *do* want to explicitly specify the config file, you would use the `-f` option:

```
$ tmux -f ~/.tmux.conf
```

The command given in your tutorial is for reloading `~/.tmux.conf` into an already running session.  It may be executed as

```
tmux-session$ tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

or by typing the tmux escape command sequence (configurable, but by default <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd>) followed by the command `source-file ~/.tmux.conf`.

---

If you want settings applied for all users, you can set them in `/etc/tmux.conf`.  This will be read automatically when *any* user starts `tmux`.

If you want settings applied for *a particular user*, set them in `~/.tmux.conf`.  This will be read automatically when that user starts `tmux`, and will be applied on top of (overriding) any global preferences from `/etc/tmux.conf`.

You should not as an ordinary user be sourcing `/root/.tmux.conf`.  If you want this user to have the same settings as previously configured for `root`, either make them global settings, or copy the `/root/.tmux.conf` into `~/.tmux.conf` so that the user has her *personal* copy of the `tmux` configuration.

Comment: because i am running tmux in another user, how could I do `source-file root/.tmux.conf`, because it says permission denied.